# MongoDB find record sample script for jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to get accurate results by using the MongoDB script as below :
db.user.find({ "name" : "jxd" })

[image]

But,unfortunately，it only give me "OK".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen when more than one entry is returned, i.e. your "user" schema contains multiple documents with the name of "jxd".

Try adding [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) to the end of your query like:

```
db.user.find({ "name" : "jxd" }).toArray()
```

and you should see the relevant output.

For more MongoDB Load Testing tips and tricks refer to [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) guide

Comment: Thanks a lot.                                                                    db.getCollection（“user”）.find({ "name" : "jxd" }).toArray()